# Comparison of two methods of applying Stokes' theorem to a specific example

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I am trying to compare an example I have seen in different places with slightly different setups done with differential forms and double integration to just have a feel for how differential forms can help even at a very basic level.

**Differential forms:**

Calculating the circulation of the vector field $\vec F=2xzi - z \hat j +x^2 \hat k$ along the intersection of the surfaces $\{y^2 + z^2=6\}$ and $\{5x-9y+3z=11\}$ is resolved by turning the field into a one form

$$\alpha_{\vec F}=2xz \mathrm dx - z\mathrm dy+x^2\mathrm dz$$

and applying the differential operator

$$\alpha_{\vec F}=2z \mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dx + 2x \mathrm dz\wedge\mathrm dx- \mathrm dz\wedge\mathrm dy+2x\mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dz= \mathrm dy\wedge\mathrm dz$$

This is equivalent to the curl being $\vec i,$ and $\int_{\partial D} \alpha_{\vec F}=\int_{D}\mathrm \alpha_{\vec F}=\int_D \mathrm dy\wedge\mathrm dz$ is the area of the projected intersection of the cylinder with the plane on the $y,z$ plane, or $6\pi.$

**Double integrals:**

The curl of the vector field is exactly $\nabla x \vec F =1 \hat i.$ Therefore, and given the strict orientation of the curl with the $x$ axis, and that the projection of the ellipse at the intersection of the plane and cone above on the $y,z$ plane "sees" the entire boundary, and it is orthogonal to the curl, the area of integration will be the disk of radius $\sqrt 6$ on the $y,z$ plane, and flux of the curl field through the disk is easily calculated as

$$ \oint \alpha_{\vec F}=\underset{S}{\int\int}1\hat i \mathrm dS=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt 6} 1  r\mathrm dr \mathrm d \theta=6\pi$$

> Both systems seem quite straightforward. Would there be any difference in using differential forms?

Comment: Of course, these are equivalent techniques. Differential forms can sometimes be easier to compute with and generalize to higher dimensions, whereas not everything vectorial (like curl) generalizes. You might check out a few of my YouTube lectures on such things (see the link in my profile).

Comment: No. The differential forms approach is just a different (and more general) viewpoint on the traditional vector calculus approach here. They both mean exactly the same thing. In Euclidean three-dimensional space, the derivative of a 1-form is exactly the same thing as the curl of a vector field, and Stokes’ theorem says the same thing in both cases.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have enjoyed your lectures a lot (thank you), and you explain the use of forms and its concept really well. I started this question with a careless mistake, which when I corrected it on an edit, it made it very clear that this calculation was just as simple with forms or with double integrals, but I decided to leave the question un-deleted. I understand that the use of differential forms becomes quite useful in more advanced math.

Comment: Bonus points to you for realizing that to integrate $dy\wedge dz$ over $S$ all you have to do is find the area of its projection in the $yz$-plane. I did try to emphasize that in my lectures.